# What is the use of drop tag

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager

As I am new to wso2, Can some one please clarify. Thank you.

If I have a main sequence with two sequence calls in it. If first sequence has drop tag in it then second sequence executes are not?
for example:

```
<sequence name = "main">
<sequence key = "middleA"/>
<sequence key = "middleB"/>
<sequence/>
<sequence name = "middleA">
 ...
.....
</drop>
<sequence/>
```

I have seen in some sites drop tag returns 202 response to client. But some places in iterator's logic also drop tag is present. In that scenario also wso2 sends 202 to response to client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop is to stop the execution flow. In other words, to make sure logic after a drop is not executed.
Also having a drop in a nested stage will not result in a 202. Having said that if the client is expecting a response, you should use respond instead of a drop.

In an iterate scenario, the execution is broken into parallel executions. So, if you want to return from one of these forked execution paths you can use the drop mediator. Again, having a drop within a Iterate will not result a 202.

Comment: Can you please tell me Where can I find detailed documentation for wso2

Comment: @Praveenkumar Here is the official doc for the drop mediator. https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/drop-Mediator/

Comment: "a drop in a nested stage will not result in a 202", this one is not mentioned in that document. Can you please tell me in the above code <sequence key = "middleB"/> executes or not. Thank you.

Comment: @Praveenkumar Why shouldn't it execute? In you example everything executes and WSO2 will send a 202.

Comment: In sequence middleA, i added drop tag. So if drop tag returns 202, Then middleB shouldn't execute right? This is as per my understanding. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Praveenkumar yes correct.